# Select currently focused element

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, pseudo-class

I'd like to find the currently focused element in the whole document.
I tried using the `:focus` pseudoclass introduced with jQuery 1.6:

```
$(document).find(":focus")
```

But `$(document).find(":focus").length` always returns `0`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should be able to use the [`activeElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.activeElement) property of the `document`:

```
var focus = $(document.activeElement);
```

If you look at the jQuery documentation for [`:focus`](http://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/) it makes this perfectly clear:

> If you are looking for the currently focused element, $(
>   document.activeElement ) will retrieve it without having to search the
>   whole DOM tree.

It's worth noting that if no element currently has focus, `activeElement` will refer to the `body`.

Answer (score 0):

> As with other pseudo-class selectors (those that begin with a ":"), it
>   is recommended to precede :focus with a tag name or some other
>   selector; otherwise, the universal selector ("`*`") is implied. In other
>   words, the bare `$(':focus')` is equivalent to `$('*:focus')`.

If you want an alternative to `$( document.activeElement )` which will retrieve the current element that has focus you can use :

```
$(document).delegate( "*", "focus blur", function( event ) {
    var elem = $( this );
    //  here use elem.is( ":focus" ) which is your element that has focus
   //for example  : 
    elem.toggleClass( "focused", elem.is( ":focus" ) );
});
```