# Select the focused element in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

#### What I'm dealing with

In one of my tests I need to interact with a pop-up input field that is very hard to select using a regular css selector or xpath. I know, however, that this pop-up box will have the focus.

How can I use the fact that it's focused to properly assert that the input field contains some text?

Pseudocode of what I'm looking for:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_FIND_THE_ELEMENT_WITH_FOCUS
assert elem.text == "foobar"
```

#### Partial solutions I've come across:

[Possibly a working solution in Ruby:](https://saucelabs.com/blog/selenium-tips-finding-elements-by-their-focus-using-focus-a-css-pseudo-class)

```
element = @driver.find_element :css, 'input:focus'
sleep(3)

element.send_keys "Hello WebDriver!"
assert_equal(element.attribute('value'),"Hello WebDriver!")
```

[Getting the focused element with jQuery:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148707/select-currently-focused-element)

```
var focus = $(document.activeElement);
```

Could you provide a solution in **python** please?

**EDIT:**

Here's the HTML of the element:

`<div class="css-1492t68">Select a speaker...</div>`

I realized my question could've lead to some confusion as the element itself is does not have the semantic `<input>` tag but is rather a `<div>`. I suppose this is handled by the `quill-editor` library, which our dev team used when designing this app.

Here's a screenshot of the pop-up box:

[image: Screenshot of the pop-up]

Comment: can you provide some html?

Comment: However you can use explicit wait to element clickable.

Comment: You say `this window will have focus` --- does this mean the text field is in a different browser window (a pop up window)?

Comment: No sorry, I should have specified. It is in the same window and tab, it's just a pop-up box (added a screenshot to the question)

Comment: Can you provide the HTML for this input?

Comment: Can't you use the CSS class on the `<div>` to get it?

Comment: You can try the `actions` and `keys` class to try and send the keys input (particularly the `TAB` key)

Comment: @Greg Burghardt I'm afraid the class name is different every time

Comment: @demouser123 The thing is I need a reference to the element primarily for asserting that its text value is correct.

Comment: Is there a way you can give it an extra class that will be the same each time?

Comment: That would be the ideal solution and I've talked to our dev team about it. It seems impossible, however, because the whole app is built with some external _React_ libraries that I (and the dev team) have no control over.

Comment: That is what I meant by being _very hard to select using a regular css selector or xpath_

Comment: Very hard indeed. Maybe this is a timing issue? I'm wondering if `driver.switch_to.active_element` is finding that element on screen before it is visible, and JavaScript has a chance to fully initialize the quill-editor.

Comment: That is, indeed, possible. I will have a further look at that as well as on the Ruby snippet and will post an update on my question if I make any progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the element does not have a consistent CSS class, using an XPath expression is probably going to be your best bet.

You need to wait for the element to be clickable (which means intractable) by matching a `<div>` that contains the expected text, and has a CSS class that begins with `css-`. Doing this should allow enough time for JavaScript to do its thing in the browser to initialize the quill-editor and display it:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ExpectedConditions

xpath = "//div[starts-with(@class, 'css-')][contains(., 'The text you expect to find')]"
expected_condition = ExpectedConditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath))
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(expected_condition)
```

If this pop up field is directly inside a particular parent element, you can further limit your xpath expression accordingly.

If this succeeds, no error will be thrown. If it does not succeed, it should throw a WebDriverTimeoutException (or whatever this error is called in Python).

Comment: I didn't want to be too broad in my question so I left some details out. The main reason why I need to do this is because I find the `send_keys` method of `ActionChains` to be fairly unreliable. Thus, before proceeding I want to check that the field really received all of the keys and now contains the proper text.

Comment: I suppose I could put the whole condition and the `WebDriverWait` into a loop and once the wait passes I will exit it.

Comment: I wonder if the `send_keys` method seems unreliable due to a race condition. Maybe not all of the characters appear in the field, because JavaScript has not finished executing on the client before Selenium starts typing in the field.

Answer (score 0):

use:

elem = driver.switch_to.active_element

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, when I follow the given line with `print(elem.text)` it outputs nothing